# How to delete duplicates rows based on 5 columns SQL

Tags: sql, mariadb

| loading_tracking_id | loading_id | loading_num | time | event | name | name_en |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3830640 | 111111 | 105416102020 | 2021-07-01 01:59:00 | office | London | UK |
| 3830641 | 22222 | 402055656444 | 2022-03-02 08:02:13 | courier | Paris | FR |
| 3830642 | 111111 | 105416102020 | 2021-07-01 01:59:00 | office | London | UK |
| 3830643 | 111111 | 105416102020 | 2021-07-01 01:59:00 | office | London | UK |
| 3830644 | 111111 | 105416102020 | 2021-07-01 01:59:00 | office | London | UK |
| 3830645 | 111111 | 105416102020 | 2021-07-01 01:59:00 | office | London | UK |

I have almost no SQL knowledge and need help. I have a database table from which I want to delete duplicates, leaving only one result (no matter the first or the last)

I need to delete all dupications where column "loading_id" has the same data for loading_num, time, event and name. I want to delete all duplications and keep just one of them.

Server version: 10.3.37-MariaDB - MariaDB Server

```
no skills to be able to test any sql code
```

Comment: You really should tell us which single record is to be retained and why.  Also, do you actually wang to _delete_ records, or rather just _view_ your data this way?

Comment: I want to delete records and keep the original record (the lowest number in loading_tracking_id)

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE FROM MariaDB  
WHERE loading_tracking_id NOT IN
(
  SELECT MAX(loading_tracking_id) FROM MariaDB 
  GROUP BY loading_id, loading_num, time, event, name, name_en
);
```

Comment: maybe it is working but I have more then 300 000 records and it is keep loading till time out. Can you tell me how I can set time range accodring column "time"